# In Dagger 2.15,Should I need to add inject line on every Activity?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger 2.15 with Kotlin. Should I need to add inject line on every Activity? Is it dagger official document updated for using latest version?

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this)
```

Comment: need not. You can look into https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java and how they used the same

Comment: You can also extend your Activity class from DaggerActivity, so dagger will inject the graph by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I need to add inject line on every Activity?

**No**, you don't need it anymore if you extend your activity from `DaggerActivity` or from `DaggerAppCompatActivity` (if you use the support libraries).

The [DaggerActivity](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DaggerActivity.java) is already calling `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` as we can see in the source code:

```
public abstract class DaggerActivity extends Activity implements HasFragmentInjector {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    //...
}
```

---

> Is it dagger official document updated for using latest version?

At today's date the dagger [documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) for Android is **not** updated but...

### I wrote, in Kotlin, an example how you can wire everything in Dagger 2.15:

Application class extending from `DaggerApplication`

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }
}
```

Simple activity that injects a `MainPresenter`

```
class MainActivity : DaggerActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var mPresenter: MainPresenter

    //... and the mPresenter is available without anything else
}
```

The `MainPresenter` is provided by the `MainModule`

```
@Module
class MainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideMainPresenter(context: Context): MainPresenter {
        return MainPresenterImpl(context)
    }
}
```

A `BuildersModule` is necessary to bind the `MainActivity` and other "sub-components"

```
@Module
abstract class BuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainModule::class])
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

The `AppComponent` now includes our `BuildersModule` and a new dagger module called `AndroidInjectionModule` or `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` (if you use the support libraries).

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    BuildersModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Notice that we don't define all that inject() functions in this interface anymore.

*Gradle dependencies:*

```
// dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15"
// dagger android
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15' // if you use the support libraries
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"
```

Comment: I assume that I need to specify every activity, fragment, service  in `BuildersModule`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are! :) if you need to inject a resource in, for example, an activity you would need to extend your activity from `DaggerActivity` and provide it in the `BuildersModule`.